# need count to return 0 but no empty result

Tags: mysql, count

I'm using oracle server. Im trying to get a count of some rows in a table and when the result is 0, it always give me an empty result. 
I searched for an answer and find some, so I tried those different solutions, but none is working :

```
SELECT IFNULL(count(*), 0) as nb 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE id_tbl1='1' 
GROUP BY id_tbl2 
ORDER BY id_tbl2

SELECT IFNULL(count(id_tbl2), 0) as nb 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE id_tbl1='1' 
GROUP BY id_tbl2 
ORDER BY id_tbl2

SELECT COALESCE(id_tbl2, 0)  as nb 
FROM tbl1
WHERE id_tbl1='1' 
GROUP BY id_tbl2 
ORDER BY id_tbl2
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Isn't 0 equal to null (that is, nothing)?

Comment: @SimonM I don't think that integer 0 == DBNULL.  After all, you can have a nullable integer field which can hold either NULL or 0, and in that case NULL != 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY` clause so you will have result even when it's empty.

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0b31/10)

Comment: thanks, i have to make more queries to do what i want but it solved my problem :)